# When a UITableViewCell is clicked

Tags: swift, uialertview, uitableview

I have a table view cell that is clickable but at the moment does nothing. How can I put action to it? To do something when the cell is clicked. For example how can I display a alert window that takes a password filed once the cell is clicked?

Comment: didSelectedRowAt IndexPath delegate method does that for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few ways to do it, however I would reccommend using the `UITableViewDelegate` method `didSelectRowAt`. A swift example would be:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Title Here", message: "Message Here", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Okay", style: .default, handler: nil))
        present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```